# Power consumption of valve actuators

Tags: home-automation, water-circulating-heating

I would like to acquire some actuators for my radiator valves. I would like them  to consume as little electricity as possible.  I therefore consider it is better to take normally closed actuators since the radiators will be heating less time than not. Is my reasoning correct or not? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. A normally open valve will need power to close which means you would need power to keep the heat off. A normally closed valve needs power to open which means you would need power to keep the heat on. Less heating, less electricity. You would have to verify what type of valves your thermostat can operate, NC or NO.

Answer (score 1):

Depending where you want your actuators. Taco brand makes a zone valve system that you would have to solder in each loop of pipes. Depending how your system is piped.  The system is usually located close to the boiler and the actuators are closed unless being used